# Set Python location when using dynamic linking in an embedded way

Tags: python

I'm currently using static-linking to make my embedded Python 2.7 application works. But this approach has a few problems that I would like to correct by using the load on call approach.(dynamic linking).

So here is my plan:

- Let the user select the python27.dll he wants to use, as explained here: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Choosing-a-different-Python-Interpreter-installation
- Load this dll using AfxLoadLibrary()
- Call Py_Initialize() and other Python functions

My question is: Do I have to set the Python Home path using the Py_SetPythonHome() function? Is it mandatory? If yes, I would need the user to specify also the location of its Python installation, which I would want to avoid.

Comment: Depending on the platform, you may be able to detect if Python is installed, what version, and where, automatically.

Comment: But how can I know that the python27.dll selected by the user matches the installed version? Do we suppose that there is only always only one Python 2.7 installed on the user's machine?

Comment: If the user has more than one Python installed one is usually the default or active version. Regardless of whether that's v2.7 or not, as long as you have a valid path to python27.dll you should be able to dynamically load it. I don't think you need to set the Python Home path, because it doesn't seem to be needed in non-embedded situations AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In my case, Python is embedded, so I think I have to specify the Python Home path. But as you pointed out, I think it is safe to use the active version by looking in the Windows registry.

Comment: You're welcome. You can always test it without setting the Python Home path and determine if that's necessary or not.